# Having trouble getting map data for the Maldive Islands

Tags: curated-data, geographics, entity

[image]
I change the island and GeoRange from the example, but it shows the error, can anyone help me with that?

Follow link as the original example(The first and second pictures) :
https://risu.io/SOmU

```
map = GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "MaldiveIslands"]["Polygon"],
  GeoRange -> {{0, 8}, {72, 74}}, GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 2048];
image = Binarize[Image[ImageData[Image[map]][[All, All, 4]]]];
labeledArray = MorphologicalComponents[image];
```

Comment: Post the code instead of picture.

Comment: GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Gray],Entity["Island", "MaldiveIslands"]["Polygon"]},GeoRange->{{0,8}, {72,74}},GeoBackground->"Satellite",GeoZoomLevel->7]

Comment: map=GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "MaldiveIslands"]["Polygon"],GeoRange->{{0,8}, {72,74}},GeoBackground->None,ImageSize->2048];
image=Binarize[Image[ImageData[Image[map]][[All,All,4]]]];\[IndentingNewLine]labeledArray=MorphologicalComponents[image];

Comment: Edit the original problem and add the code  :)

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error message may be that `Entity["Country", "MaldiveIslands"]["Polygon"]` evaluates to `Missing["UnknownEntity", {"Country", "MaldiveIslands"}]`

The following code, which is similar to yours, evaluates without an error message.  It uses "Maldives" instead of "MaldiveIslands" and an image size of 160 instead of 2048.

```
map = GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Gray],
    Entity["Country", "Maldives"]["Polygon"]},
   GeoBackground -> None,
   GeoRange -> {{0, 8}, {72, 74}},
   ImageSize -> 160];
image = Binarize[Image[ImageData[Image[map]][[All, All, 4]]]]; 
labeledArray = MorphologicalComponents[image];
Dimensions@labeledArray

(*  {1413, 352}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
map =
 GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[None], Polygon @ CountryData["Maldives"]},
  GeoRange -> "Country",
  GeoBackground -> None,
  ImageSize -> 400]
image = Rasterize[map, "Image", RasterSize -> 400, ImageSize -> 400];
labeledArray = MorphologicalComponents[image];
Colorize[labeledArray, ColorRules -> {0 -> Red}]
```

[image]